# Pressing the ESC key closes all popups instead of closing the recent one

Tags: bug, popup

As the title says, Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> closes all popups instead of closing the recent one.

For example

1. Press <kbd>edit (1)</kbd> on a question having a suggested edit pending review:

   [image]
2. A popup with the suggested edit will appear. Press the <kbd>Reject</kbd> button:

   [image]
3. Another popup with "**Why are you rejecting this edit?**" appears. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> closes both popups instead of closing the recently opened one.

Comment: And why would this be a bug, rather than just the way it works? How about I don't want to press Esc twice if I realise I don't want to do anything about the suggested edit? How many times does this bother people either way?

Comment: From idle curiosity: Is there any situation other than viewing a suggested edit on a post and choosing to reject it where you can even have two popups at once?

Comment: Escape doing any of this is annoying; us ViM users that, out of reflex, hit escape when we're done with an edit (to `:wq<CR>` or something) end up discarding the edit completely.

Comment: @TZHX flag => should be closed... => off-topic because... is another.

Comment: @MikeMc No -- that seems to just reuse the same modal window (you can't move it and see the other one beneath).

Comment: @BillWoodger: because it's inconsistent with, well, just about every modern graphical interface? Unless there's a pressing reason for it to behave in a special way, consistency makes the site less surprising/confusing...

Comment: @psmears It is like it is. For the one person in 800,000 (figures are invented and potentially hyperboleic) who has done this and been immediately confused (and even though they now know for next time) it may be a bit of a stretch to expect much to be done about it. Box. Box. Oh, don't want that box. Esc. Oh, did want the first box vs Box. Box. Oh, don't want that box. Esc. Great, that's save me a whole extra Esc! That's for the 1 in 600,000 who've discovered this and like it.

Comment: @BillWoodger: I didn't say it's a bug with a huge impact - that's an entirely different question ;-). But of the 1 in 800,000 that came across this, 84% were surprised at the double closure, and 73% agreed it should be consistent with other UIs. (See, I can make up figures too ;-) )

Comment: @psmears And that's still less than the 100% of the 1 in 600,000 :-) . I agree that consistency is a very good idea and that to not be consistent requires good reason. It's a design issue. This particular item would need to be evaluated. If it is new (and no such reason) there is more impetus for fix than if it has been around for a few years (when there's a danger of breaking other people's work routines by the "fix"). Inconsistency is a good reason for not including something in a design, it is not a good reason for a "fix" in something which is "mature" without further checking.

Comment: @TZHX Hmm. I can't think of any other situation where one can see two popups at once...